# like and comment section: in django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'd like to put like and comment section in my blog project with some info like no. of likes and comments and also show user who comment on it in django project but don't know how.
its a simple blog so i just want a like button and a comment button, above that its need to show how much likes and comment that post have and at least need to show one comment below that just like a normal blog have 
her is my html code:

```
{% for post in post %}
<article class="media mt-4">
<div class="media-body">
    <img class="rounded-circle article-img" id="dp" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}">
    <div class="article-metadata">
        <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'Love Travel-User' post.author.username %}">{{ post.author }}</a>
        <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
    </div>
    <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'User-Posts-Details' post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
    <img src="{{ post.img.url }}" class="article-img">
    <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
</div>
</article>
{% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
class PostListViews(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'userpost/posts.html'
    context_object_name = 'post'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 7
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics')
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author= models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('User-Posts-Details', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: Should the likes and comments appear in your list view?  Also can you clarify what information you want to show, perhaps with an example?

Comment: well its a blog so i just want a like button and a comment button, above that its need to show how much likes and comment that post have and at least need to show one comment below that just like a normal blog have

Comment: Please bring more focus to your question, show what you have tried and what issues you've faced.

Comment: i just want to add comment and like section for my blog posts like all sites has e.g facebook, instagram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will not give the code but I will explain how to do it.

I will help you with the comments part.

You have to create a model Comment link with a Foreign key to Post model. This will allow you to create Comment objects, then you will be able to stock them in your database and display them.

For the view, I prefer Function Based View, it will be easier for you.

And you have to create a ModelForm. To simplify creation of comments you should create an other html page.

I hope it was clear, 
Do not hesitate if you have any questions !

Comment: ok i can create model in which i need to put username of user and comment like textfield then i need to link it with post model with foreign key and in views i need to make function based view to address it. But what should i write in form and shouldn't it in same html where posts are?

Comment: i also have a html for post details should i put there?

Comment: In post detail you can display the comments link to your post. But to create a new comment I recommend you to use something like : comment_create.html, I find this way easier.
And your comment model should look something like that :

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post',related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_list')

Comment: ok ok thnk u alot. Can you tell me what should i write in forms?

Comment: class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Comment
        fields = ('author','text')

That's what you should write on your forms.py !

If your problem is solve you can put a check on my answer ! I'm listening if you have further questions and sorry I can't write better code in comment if you want I can update my answer